# Configure CA to connect to server with Ethernet

Tags: arduino-ide, esp32, ethernet

I'm using Ethernet module ENC28J60 with ESP32 on Arduino IDE.

I could establish a secure connection using `WifiClientSecure.h`
here code

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>

const char* ssid = "wifi";
const char* password = "1234567890";

const char* serverName = "https://myserver.com/v1";

const char* userName = "admin";
const char* pass = "pass";

unsigned long previous;


const char* rootCACertificate =
  "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n"
  ...
  "-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println();

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.print("Connecting to WiFi ..");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    Serial.print('.');
    delay(1000);
  }

  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

}

void loop() {
  if ((WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED))
  {
    WiFiClientSecure client;

    client.setCACert(rootCACertificate);
    HTTPClient https;

    Serial.print("[HTTPS] begin...\n");
    if (https.begin(client, serverName))
    {
      https.setAuthorization(userName, pass);
      https.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
      ...
      https.end();

    }
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.printf("Unable to connect to wifi\n");
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Waiting 60sec before the next round...");
  delay(60000);
}
```

But there is no support for Ethernet.
Could anyone suggest a way to connect to server with EthernetENC or any other Library?

Comment: if you use ethernet module supported by the esp32, you can use the code you have. https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/tree/master/libraries/Ethernet/examples

Comment: @Juraj So I just need to change Ethernet Module to Ethernet Hardware TCP/IP W5500 Ethernet Network Module? How to configure CA?

Comment: you will use the same code as with WiFi. only at the low level it will go through the W5500